# R package `exams` - not importing R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, r-exams

I recently installed the R package `exams` in order to generate some qti format quizzes for a course I am about to teach, but have been unable to import R markdown files.

I tried with the example file switzerland.Rmd available here: 
http://www.r-exams.org/templates/switzerland/

Here's the error I am getting when I try to run `exams2qti21`:

```
> exams2qti21("../Downloads/switzerland.Rmd")
sh: 1: +RTS: not found
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 127
```

How can I fix this?

I am running R 3.4.4 on Ubuntu Xenial.

Comment: This appears to be a problem with `pandoc` as interfaced through the `rmarkdown` package. Could you say ` rmarkdown:::pandoc()` and verify that the reported path actually exists/works? Possibly a newer pandoc version might be needed or something like this...

Comment: This comment pointed me in the right direction.  Turns out the namespace where pandoc was defined was knitr, not rmarkdown, but when I typed `knitr:::pandoc()`, I got the error "Error in knitr:::pandoc() : 
  Please install pandoc first: http://pandoc.org".  I used Synaptic to install pandoc, and the command works now!

Comment: @AchimZeileis, would you like to write up an answer that I can mark as the correct answer?

Comment: Thanks! I suspected that this is due to a wrong or missing pandoc installation but wasn't sure. I have expanded my comment into a proper answer now.

Comment: I was going through some old `r-exams` questions to see whether any of them are still open. I noticed that you haven't flagged my response as the correct answer (as you suggested above). Would you please consider doing so?

Comment: Sorry for not doing so sooner!

Comment: No worries, thanks for doing so now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error does not come from `exams` itself but from the `rmarkdown` package which is leveraged by `exams` to call the `pandoc` converter (for converting Markdown to HTML in this case). It appears that on your system `pandoc` is either not installed at all, not in the search path, or not installed correctly.

If `pandoc` is not installed at all, then you need to install it. On Ubuntu you can use the usual package managers to install it, e.g., `sudo apt-get install pandoc` or via synaptic etc. If you use RStudio then this also ships with a `pandoc` binary (at least on Windows) so that you don't need to install it yourself.

To check at which path `pandoc` is installed (if it is), you can use `rmarkdown::pandoc()`.